# Adding multiple images on django admin site and showing on detail page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm working on a portfolio project and I want to add multiple images on the Django admin site then displaying one of the header_image and title of a project on the home/list page (like card class functionality in bootstrap) and other images on the detail page. Is it possible?

`Models.py`

```
class MultiImage(models.Model): 
    header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    other_images = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/') # want this to be multiple image field
    description = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', 'updated')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> index.html

```
{% for project in projects %}
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
  <div class="portfolio-wrap">
   <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
   <div class="portfolio-links">
    <a href="{{ project.image.url }}" data-gall="portfolioGallery" class="venobox" title="{{ project.title }}"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="{% url 'detail' project.id %}" title="More Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

detail.html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="portfolio-details-container">

  <div class="owl-carousel portfolio-details-carousel">
   <img src="{% static 'img/portfolio-details-1.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
   <!-- all the images goes here -->
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio-info">
   <h3>Project Information</h3>
   <ul>
    <li><strong>Project </strong>: {{ project.title }}</li>
    <li><strong>Project Link to GitHub:</strong>: <a href="{{ project.link }}">{{ project.title }}</a </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

[list/index page img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONnZa.png)

[detail page img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imbaq.jpg)
[detail page img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTx97.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have several images stored against a single `MultiImage` object, the best way to do this is to create a separate image model (where you will store all of the images) and then point them back to the `MultiImage` instance with a foreign key. It will look something like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # add in anything else you want here
    image = models.ImageField((upload_to='media/')
    multiImage = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='other_images')
```

This will mean, each image you create 'points' to a `MultiImage` instance. The `related_name` property is how you get all of the images you need. For example:

```
multi_image_instance = MultiImage.objects.get(id=...)
images = multi_image_instance.other_images # this will return a QuerySet
```

In the detail view you can do something like:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src={image.image.url} />
{% endfor %}
```